# Static Google maps 2 pins

Tags: google-maps

Is there a way I can zoom my google maps and the two pins will always show or focused?

Answer (score 0):

Set the center and zoom for the map :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [marker locations](http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Markers) and [implicit positioning](http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#ImplicitPositioning)

Answer (score 0):

its not possible. if u r using two pins, middle of the two pins will be the center of the map(Google Static map API determines the center of the map).. so if you increase the zoom value u may not seen the pin positions.

Maps API automatically determines the zoom level by default..